# fails to find cabal file when file present

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, haskell-platform

I have the following directory structure:
`ls`:

```
  Project.Cabal
  LICENSE
  Setup.hs
  cabal.sandbox.config
  dist
  src
     Main.hs
     otherstuff
  tests
```

running `cabal install --only-denendencies` produces:
  cabal: Error reading local package.
  Couldn't find .cabal file in: .

running `cabal install -v3 --only-dependencies` produces relatively lengthy output that I'm currently choosing not to post in full to avoid being immediatly overwhelming. The final few lines before error are:

```
The package database already exists:
/Users/abraham/github/hamming_distance/.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2-packages.conf.d
Reading available packages...
Reading installed packages...
("/usr/bin/ghc-pkg",["dump","--package-db=/Users/abraham/github/hamming_distance/.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2-packages.conf.d","-v0"])
("/usr/bin/ghc",["--print-libdir"])
Found no modified add-source deps.
Reading installed packages...
("/usr/bin/ghc-pkg",["dump","--global","-v0"])
("/usr/bin/ghc-pkg",["dump","--package-db=/Users/abraham/github/hamming_distance/.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2-packages.conf.d","-v0"])
("/usr/bin/ghc",["--print-libdir"])
Reading available packages...
cabal: Error reading local package.
Couldn't find .cabal file in: .
```

Similiarly, running `cabal build` produces:

```
Package has never been configured. Configuring with default flags. If this
fails, please run configure manually.
cabal: No cabal file found.
Please create a package description file <pkgname>.cabal

While running `cabal build -v3` produces:
..
..
..
The package database already exists:
/Users/abraham/github/hamming_distance/.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2-packages.conf.d
Reading installed packages...
("/usr/bin/ghc-pkg",["dump","--global","-v0"])
("/usr/bin/ghc-pkg",["dump","--package-db=/Users/abraham/github/hamming_distance/.cabal-sandbox/x86_64-osx-ghc-7.10.2-packages.conf.d","-v0"])
("/usr/bin/ghc",["--print-libdir"])
Reading available packages...
cabal: No cabal file found.
Please create a package description file <pkgname>.cabal
```

What is going on? Why is my cabal failing? And how do I fix it?

Comment: Seems that file names are case sensitive on your OS. Try to rename `Project.Cabal` to `Project.cabal`.

Comment: Thank you! If you write it up as answer, I will accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's already a hint in the error message:

> ```
> cabal: No cabal file found.
> Please create a package description file <pkgname>.cabal
> ```

Cabal [only looks for `.cabal` files](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.22.6.0/docs/Distribution-Simple-Utils.html#v:findPackageDesc), not `.Cabal`. Change the extension of your `Project.Cabal` to the lowercase one.